# With Pandas, how do I add a timestamp index column to an existing .csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

My current .csv file looks something like this:

```
         Account    Type    Value
index    
0        abc123     abc     123
1        cba123     bcd     234
2        abc321     cde     345
```

New entries are appended to the file every few minutes, and what time they're added is an important bit of data.  So, I want to change the simple ordered index column into a timestamp column, basically containing the results of `datetime.now()`.

In other words, I want it to look like this:

```
Timestamp                     Account    Type    Value
2020-09-08 08:36:38.188986    abc123     abc     123
2020-09-08 08:42:36.491590    cba123     bcd     234
2020-09-08 08:48:38.208422    abc321     cde     345
```

The closest I've gotten to that so far is by using this:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df.index.name = "Timestamp"
```

The problem is that although this does add the timestamp column as desired, the timestamps being added are all from 1970, like so:

```
Timestamp                        Account    Type    Value
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000    abc123     abc     123
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001    cba123     bcd     234
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002    abc321     cde     345
```

How do I make an index column consisting of a timestamp from when that row is actually appended to my .csv file, and not from 50 years ago?

UPDATE: I think part of what was making it behave oddly is the source of my data, which is a list converted to a dataframe:

```
data = ib.accountSummary() # produces a list
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # converts list to dataframe
```

I figured out something that works (see my own self-answer below), but I'm still puzzled about the 1970 thing.  Why on earth did that happen?  Is there any way I can rewrite that snippet to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer: Coming at it from a different direction, I did manage to add a column containing timestamps, then set that as index:

```
now = datetime.now()
df["Timestamp"] = now
df.set_index("Timestamp", inplace=True)
```

Not the nice elegant one-line solution I was aiming for, but I'll definitely settle for a 3 line solution that works!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
```

`df.append(pd.DataFrame(data, index=[date]))`

Comment: Hrm.  Thanks, but this is still leaving me with just the default ordered index--not sure why! Might have something to do with what I'm pulling the data from:     `data =ib.accountSummary()   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)`